# Question about tangent vector of a curve in a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

I am reading "Methods of Information geometry by Amari" and got a small doubt here. As you see in the image they have defined a curve $\gamma: I\to S$ where $S$ is an $n-$dimensional manifold and $\xi^{i}$ is a coordinate on $S$, My doubt is why the author said the derivative of $\gamma$ at $p$, I think it should be derivative of $\gamma$ at $a$.Since $a$ is in domain.and what does the following mean $(\frac{d\gamma}{dt})_{p}=\dot\gamma(a)$

Comment: This is a matter of notation.  $(\frac{d\gamma}{dt})_{p}$ is defined to be the derivative of  $f:I\to S\to \mathbb R^n$ given by $f(t)=(\xi\circ \gamma)(t)$   at $a$.

Comment: @Matematleta Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I didn't think one-liners were appropriate for answers.

Comment: @Matematleta Sometimes "keep it short" is a good motto.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of notation. $\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)_{p}$ is defined to be the derivative of $f:I\to S\to \mathbb R^n,$ given by $f(t)=(\xi\circ \gamma)(t).$

Comment: Think of it as the *tangent vector to the curve* $\gamma$ at the point $p = \gamma(a)$. (The direction is independent of the parametrization, although the length is not.)